# I need to transmit 100khz /90khz FSk at 9600 baud over 4km

Tags: cables

What cable characteristics should I look for when designing a copper (or other) conductor cable for transmitting FSK @ 100kHz/90khz, 3V pp in order to achieve a maximum attenuation of not more than 26dB over 4km?

I expected to need to use shielded twisted pair but advice on alternatives is welcome.

Comment: why do you need shielded?  I get the feeling that ADSL exceeds that on ordinary phone cables.

Comment: Unshielded would be normal. Shield mainly adds massive capacitance to ground, hence attenuation.

Comment: capacitance to ground shouldn't cause attenuation in a transmission line, (it will change the impedance though)

Comment: Is tis an assignment or a real-world task. (Either are OK)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it's likely a requirement posted from an RFQ - I used to get that sort of rubbish turning up in my e-mails all the time.

Comment: 3Vpp is a little too low for such a long transmission line. Think about differential interface, like RS-485.

Comment: @Andyaka It's only terrible if you hadn't missed the 9600 in the heading :-). You could have said that it was a bit terrible, and maybe said to watch this space and mark your words, or that between starts and stops there may be some data , but ...

Comment: What happened to my comment? Radio modules might work if it's line of site and directional antennas.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your carrier is spectrally fairly pure (no harmonics), single-ended either RG58 or the ubiquitous RG59 will do. [This site](http://www.arrg.us/pages/Loss-Calc.htm) can be used for your own calculations.

Like I say, this will assume that your 90 kHz/100 kHz are pretty good sine waves. If you're using logic levels, you'll need to specify a much greater bandwidth to handle the harmonics, but even so there are coaxes available which will do the job.

Comment: It is a real world task....Thanks for for all who have answered including peter J

Answer (score 0):

4 km of cable is a lot of $$ (especially something like RG-59, as suggested in another answer).

As an alternative, if you can't do direct wireless because it's not line of sight, why not use two cellular modems, with the cheapest unlimited data plans you can find (there are several plans that offer high-speed to begin with, then throttle down to like 64 kbs after 5G for example, which would still be perfect for you).